# Create Apex class using Python

Tags: apex, api

My plan is to create integration in which i need to be able to receive webhooks from salesforce. I already have connected app and access to salesforce API.

I am familiar with the steps i need to do before i can recieve webhooks (I already did this using UI). From my understanding the flow is:

1. Add remote site setting: to allow sending hooks to external site
2. Add apex class definition: This class should have method for creating and sending request.
3. Add trigger for SObject: in this trigger you specify events, when the trigger should be called and then you import and use class from step 2. to send this data as a request.

How i can do this using simple-salesforce package or using requests ?

This is class i am struggling (cant find how to) to upload to salesforce

```
public class Webhook implements HttpCalloutMock {


    public static HttpRequest request;
    public static HttpResponse response;

    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        request = req;
        response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response;
    }

    public static String jsonContent(List<Object> triggerNew, List<Object> triggerOld) {
        String newObjects = '[]';
        if (triggerNew != null) {
            newObjects = JSON.serialize(triggerNew);
        }

        String oldObjects = '[]';
        if (triggerOld != null) {
            oldObjects = JSON.serialize(triggerOld);
        }

        String userId = JSON.serialize(UserInfo.getUserId());

        String content = '{"new": ' + newObjects + ', "old": ' + oldObjects + ', "userId": ' + userId + '}';
        return content;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callout(String url, String content) {

        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Webhook());
        }

        Http h = new Http();

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody(content);

        h.send(req);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a class instead of creating a package and installing such package in the org? Does the class need to be dynamic in some way?

Comment: no it does not need to be dynamic. Could the package be installed via API ? because the main idea is to integrate Salesforce sobject rows (Accounts, Leads, ....) with our system. And i want to receive newly created, updated, or deleted items via webhooks and then apply this change in our system so items are in sync in both systems.

Comment: i found a project which basically does what i need to do, but im not very proficient in scala so reverse engeneering specific REST calls would take so much time and it is basically 3 calls that i need to know how to build. This is project: https://github.com/jamesward/salesforce-webhook-creator

Comment: If you create a package with your class on it, you can just install the package through the API, yes. But for your specific requirement you don't need Apex, I think. You might wanna take a look at the Change Data Capture documentation instead of building this from scratch: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST

You can create Apex Class through REST API. This is an example in Apex, but you can rewrite it on python. Basically, you need you `instance_url` and `access_token` from authorization response. Replace `RestUtils.getSalesforceDomainURL()` with `instance_url` and `UserInfo.getSessionId()` with `access_token`. That will do it.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(RestUtils.getSalesforceDomainURL() + '/services/data/v59.0/sobjects/ApexClass');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

String json = '{"Name": "YourClassName", "Body": "';
json += 'your class hoes here';
json += '"}';

req.setBody(json);
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
```

SOAP

To upload class to your organization, you need to use Metadata API. For this:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_get_WSDLs.htm - Build Client Applications for Metadata API
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/file_based_zip_file.htm - Deploy Metadata with the Zip File

Here is an example of Apex Class Metadata:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_classes.htm

Comment: provided example throws 503 response code.

Comment: but isnt Tooling API what i need to use ? specifically POST /tooling/sobjects/ApexClass ?

Comment: You are right, it is also possible with REST API (not tooling api, but I guess that's also an option), will update the answer. @JanBalucha